# ios7 // safari // manage/disable history effects

Tags: safari, ios7

Is there any way to manipulate or disable the new history effects that occur when swiping in from the side of the display?

Or a way to recognize if the swipe or button was used for going back/forth in the history?

Answer (score 1):

**There's no API for this.**

The only "solution" is to get users to save your web app to the home screen (you'll need to set the `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` meta tag).